# How to check android application on my android phone?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I create one application and i need to test it on my android phone..what is process?
And also i need to check sms application how to use sim card in emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to develop?

Assuming you are using Eclipse, under settings on your phone enable USB debugging. Plug your phone in and when you go to run your application it will give you the option of testing on your phone. I think you might find this useful:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html

Answer (score 2):

probably I'm being repetitive but I suggest you to read this blog entry, it's pretty straight forward and it has screenshots that will guide you through the process

[running your android applications on your phone instead of the emulator](http://www.mybringback.com/travis-android-help/197/testing-your-application-on-your-actual-phone/)